# how to find element inside list of lists?

Tags: python, sql, list, sqlite

so I have  fetched a list of lists from my sqlite database by the query:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=? OR total=? ',('not ready', another))
```

it returns :

```
[('new item ', '1', '6', '6', 1, 'not ready'),
 ('new item ', '1', '6', '6', 2, 'not ready'),
 ('item1', '36', '3', '108', 2, 'not ready'),
 ('new item ', '1', '2', '2', 3, 'not ready'),
 ('item1', '36', '1', '36', 3, 'not ready'),
 ('new item ', '1', '5', '5', 4, 'not ready'),
 ('new item ', '1', '1', '1', 4, 'not ready')]
```

what I'm trying to do is :

1. get all the lists where the 4th element is equal together in one list
2. or make a SQLite query where it gets all the similar lists in the fourth element together.

like that :

```
[
    [
        ('new item ', '1', '6', '6', 1, 'not ready')
    ],
    [
        ('new item ', '1', '6', '6', 2, 'not ready'),
        ('item4', '5', '6', '30', 2, 'not ready'),
        ('item3', '33', '3', '99', 2, 'not ready')
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Create a dictionary whose key is the 4th item and value is the list of all rows with that item.

Comment: What does "4th element is equal together in one list" mean?

Comment: If the query is already returning all of the rows you require, then I generally find doing the grouping logic in code easier than doing the sql query.

Comment: @ScottHunter for instance ' ('new item ', '1', '6', '6', 2, 'not ready')' the 4th element is 2 here

Comment: @ScottHunter He means to group the results by the value of the 4th column.

Comment: I think you mean the 5th element. The first list has 1, the second list has 2, etc.